# How to close window OSX?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode6

I wanted to create an application that ***mainly*** only involves the status bar. So far I have created the status bar item using `NSMenu` and `NSStatusBar` and I have also removed the dock icon with this bit of code on load:

```
[NSApp setActivationPolicy: NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory];
```

But what I still have is the `NSWindow` appearing when opening the app.

How can I prevent this? I also would like to be able to re-open it.

---

I have come up with a horrible way to close it:

```
[_mainView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Where `_mainView` is the main `NSView` in my viewcontroller that is conected to the `nswindow`.

I then want to be able to open the window again but with this time a table. But I get the error:

```
<Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const: conn 0x18de3 token 0x31fffffffffdafd
```

When resetting the frame back to the original size.

Also if I close the NSView that then means I can't re-open the view again.

---

This is a long winded explanation of an application that can control whether the window the viewcontroller is in, is opened or close.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `rootViewController` in the `appDelegate` to nil?

Comment: @Fennelouski may you expand a little?

Comment: If you don't need the window controller at all, delete it (and also the view controller)  in Interface Builder

Comment: but then the whole program  I have written won't run on load?

Comment: The way I've always hidden windows at launch is `[_window orderOut:self];` ... if that's what you're trying to do, then `[_window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];` if you want to show it.

Comment: how do I create `_window` though?!

Comment: `_window` is the window you want to hide; `_window` means `self.window`, just abbreviated. so try that, the window associated with your view controller, or `_mainView`

Comment: But the instance variable `window` doesn't come out of nowhere?

Comment: Why did you edit your question and write "Please see new question", mark an answer as correct and put a link going to a new question asking essentially the same thing? It's is not making a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a NSStatusBar item app that only shows in the status bar  and not in the Dock or Application Tabbing. And not show any of the normal menus. i.e file,edit,view and so on..

You need to add the [Application is agent (UIElement)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256)  - (Boolean) **YES**  key - value to the application info.plist.

[image]

---

And also make sure that the windows 'visible At Launch' is switch off in the attribute inspector.

---

**Update:**

In a none storyboard application (OS X)

Setting the 'visible At Launch' to off in IB for a window, will stop the window appearing at launch.

But with a storyboard application. This will not work.

The 'visible At Launch' is already set to be off. But regardless of that, the window will always show.

(I think this is part of the design of storyboards and Human interface guidelines by apple. Maybe because they stem from iOS and there should always be a window present.)

There are possibly a few ways of changing this behaviour but I found that if you uncheck the **initial Controller** in the Attributes Inspector for the NSWindowController

[image]

This will stop the window showing up at launch. Which makes sense since the app now does not have any instructions to show anything initially.

To open the window you can simply link a menu item to the NSWindowController's *Presenting Segue* **Show:**  method in IB.

---

If you want to open the window programmatically, then you have to re point to the controller in the code.

- In IB select the NSWindowController again
- Go to the Identity Inspector.
- Give the Storyboard ID the identity "Main"

[image]

- Now go to your **AppDelegate.h** file and add a the Property and IBAction:

  ```
           @property (strong) IBOutlet NSWindowController *winController;

            -(IBAction)showWindow:(id)sender;
  ```
- Then go to the **AppDelegate.m** file and add this code in the **applicationDidFinishLaunching**

  ```
           NSStoryboard *storyBoard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

           NSWindowController * main = [storyBoard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];

           _winController = main;
  ```

(note just adding the controller by linking it directly with a property in the AppDelegate did not work for me)

- Now add the IBAction code to the **AppDelegate.m**

  ```
           -(IBAction)showWindow:(id)sender {

            [_winController showWindow:self];


           }
  ```

You will need to link the IBAction as normal to which ever menu item you want to open the window via IB.

Comment: I have tried that with no luck. Also I have updated my question please see

Comment: @Maximilian What about the 'visible At Launch'

Comment: This is the same exact thing as `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory`

Comment: @Maximilian Try commenting that out and see if it works in the Attributes panel.

Comment: @markhunte I have turned it off on the NSWindow (initial controller) still showing up if I don;t do my hack

Comment: @MaximilianAre you able to post the project on dropbox or something, this is not normal.

Comment: @Maximilian "commenting what out?" the NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory code. But see my last comment

Comment: i commented it out no difference

Comment: Unfortunately I wont be able to put it on dropbox it holds a lot of sensitive data

Comment: @Maximilian   [NSApp setActivationPolicy: NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory]; will hide the Dockect. But it will not stop a window showing. You have to use set visible at launch to off

Comment: How do I use `setVisible:` for the NSWindow though?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88233/discussion-between-markhunte-and-maximilian).