# Closing OSX window on load

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have come up with a taskbar program that is able to shut and close a window. Key code being:

```
-(void) openWindow{
    NSLog(@"Opening Window");
    //put infront of all other apps
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    //show window
    [[_myView window] orderFront:self];
}

-(void) closeWindow{
    NSLog(@"Closing Window");
    //hide window
    [[_myView window] orderOut:self];
}
```

This is working [perfectly](https://mega.nz/#F!o8djXRBJ!fvbNzZiDOCLrw4L6DjGXcQ).

The only issue is, I now want the program to start off with the window closed but when I set this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self closeWindow];

}
```

Nothing happens and the window stays open?? And before you ask - Yes 'Visible At Launch' is switched off! Haha

---

If I add a 0.001 second delay in the view did load it works!!

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.001 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self closeWindow];
});
```

but then there is a horrible flicker...

Comment: how about not opening the window to begin with?  :-)

Comment: That is the what I am asking... Ha

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close window OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184722/how-to-close-window-osx) How is this question any different from the one you've marked correct and abandoned?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a viewWillAppear method, try to put your [self closeWindow] in.
Or maybe you try to close the window before she is visible so the code to show window is executed after your call to closeWindow.

Put some breakpoints if needed to see the order of the methods's execution.